# I can't write in raspberry pi.. It doesn't accept commands .it write in small box in the referred place . What's the solution

Tags: raspberry-pi-desktop

[image]
When i write any command it doesn't write in the write place

Comment: You haven't written anything. Or are you saying you can't input anything in that box?

Comment: Yes i can't write any command . I can't use the program. When i write anything it appears at the bottom of the screen not in it's place and it doesn't run

Comment: That's happened in all the programs i try to format the card and reinstall the operating system it give me the same result

Comment: Have you clicked the mouse in the window to give it focus?

Comment: Yes I did and it gives the same result

Comment: what program is that? never mind, I see it is Thonny - it's odd that there's no title bar, nor anything in the status bar at the bottom